# uitableview fill equally does not work in simulator

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, uistackview

I have searched couple of days to solve my fill equally problem but I could not find any solution. I added all screenshot for obtained both using stack view and equal widths. Everything looks perfect on the storyboard but when i run it. It looks like [image]

Equal widths:

[image]

Stack view fill equally:

[image]

All custom class identifiers are used properly.

I will appreciate for providing solution to this problem.

Comment: Please share screenshot that shows stackview properties you have set

Comment: Also need to see how you have set constraint of stackview than can give you some solution

Comment: First, make sure you have set the custom cell class to the Cell Prototype and ***not*** to the `Content View`. Second, if you are using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the row heights, your stack view *also* needs a Bottom constraint.

Comment: I do not how to thanks user DonMag :). Maybe I missed but I did not see anywhere this information. My mistake was setting Content View as custom view, it should be regular UIView. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments...

The issue was that the class for the `Content View` had been set to the custom `UITableViewCell` class. *Only* the prototype cell itself should be set to that class... the Content View should remain at its default `UIView`.

It's actually a common mistake.